# WebSocket Connect Error "reason=Failed to open local endpoint"

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, websocket, jetty

When connecting to a WebSocket server using jetty, onWebSocketError() was called on the client side and a TimeOut occurred.

After that, when the client reconnects to the server, onWebSocketConnect() is called, but immediately onWebSocketClose() is called, the statusCode value is 1006, and the reason value is "Failed to open local endpoint".

On the server side, onWebSocketConnect() is called, and immediately after that, onWebSocketClose() is called. The value of statusCode is 1000 and the value of reason is "null".

What shall I do, in order to solve this?

client log
13:17:01.626    ERROR : onError call. Throwable:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout
13:17:01.635    INFO    : Websocket ReConnect. retryCount:1
13:17:01.636    INFO    : onConnect call.
13:17:01.636    ERROR    : onClose call. statusCode=1006 reason=Failed to open local endpoint
13:17:01.735    INFO    : Websocket ReConnect. retryCount:2
13:17:01.736    INFO    : onConnect call.
13:17:01.736    ERROR    : onClose call. statusCode=1006 reason=Failed to open local endpoint
13:17:01.835    INFO    : Websocket ReConnect. retryCount:3
13:17:01.836    INFO    : onConnect call.
13:17:01.836    ERROR    : onClose call. statusCode=1006 reason=Failed to open local endpoint
13:17:01.936    INFO    : Websocket ReConnect. retryCount:4
13:17:01.936    INFO    : onConnect call.
13:17:01.937    ERROR    : onClose call. statusCode=1006 reason=Failed to open local endpoint
13:17:02.036    INFO    : Websocket ReConnect. retryCount:5
13:17:02.037    INFO    : onConnect call.
13:17:02.037    ERROR    : onClose call. statusCode=1006 reason=Failed to open local endpoint

server log
13:17:01.636    INFO  : onConnect call.
13:17:01.697    ERROR : onClose call. statusCode=1000 reason=null
13:17:01.736    INFO  : onConnect call.
13:17:01.797    ERROR : onClose call.  statusCode=1000 reason=null
13:17:01.836    INFO  : onConnect call.
13:17:01.897    ERROR : onClose call.  statusCode=1000 reason=null
13:17:01.936    INFO  : onConnect call.
13:17:01.997    ERROR : onClose call.  statusCode=1000 reason=null
13:17:02.036    INFO  : onConnect call.
13:17:02.097    ERROR : onClose call.  statusCode=1000 reason=null

While this problem occurred, several sessions were communicating at the same time. I think that the firewall settings are unlikely to be the cause.
Client and server are separate EC2 instances, same jetty version 9.4.48.v2022062.